# How to access array value in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have an array `categoryDataString`

```
[{"ID":"1","Category":"first"},
{"ID":"2","Category":"second"},
{"ID":"3","Category":"third"}]
```

I want to access the specific value from the array. like the name of the 2nd category.

I tried
1st

```
 console.log(categoryDataString[0].ID)
```

result

```
undefined
```

2nd

```
console.log(categoryDataString)
```

result

```
[{"ID":"1","Category":"first"},{"ID":"2","Category":"second"},{"ID":"3","Category":"third"}]
```

This is my code

```
 const categoryDataString = JSON.stringify(categoryData)
    const categoryData = useCategoryData()
    useEffect(() => {
            setDataLoad(DataLoaded + 1)
            setSelected(categoryDataString.Category)
            console.log(categoryDataString[0].ID)
            console.log(categoryDataString)
        }, [categoryData])
```

This is my Itemdata.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'

export const useCategoryData = (props) => {
    const [Category, setCategory] = useState('')
    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('https://www.amrutras.com/Category.php')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                {
                    setCategory(responseJson)

                    // responseJson.map((item) => Alert.alert(item.Name))
                }

                // Showing response message coming from server after inserting records.
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error)
            })
    }, [])

    return Category
}

export default useCategoryData
```

Comment: You can access the array by its variable name.

Comment: Is the array filled after asynchronous call?

Comment: yes. I am setting this array from response of fetch.

Comment: please share the whole code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you get undefined because categoryDataString is well, a string. so you would need to converty it to an object then access the properties as such:

```
const categoryDataObject = JSON.parse(categoryDataString);
console.log(categoryDataObject[0].ID)
```

you could also try accessing the categoryData without needing to convert it to a json string in the first place, so:

```
console.log(categoryData[0].ID)
```